# How do I find the data directory for MySQL Server 5.7 on Windows 10?

Tags: mysql, netbeans-8, datadirectory

I've been snooping around and I found that some people's `MySQL Server 5.7` directory had a data directory within their `MySQL Server 5.7` directory along with `bin`, `lib` etc. but mine doesn't. I've tried reinstalling multiple ways and I have concluded that the data directory is not there.

Upon launching the MySQL server I get ERROR:

> failed to set datadir to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.7\data\

By the way, I am using `MySQL Server 5.7` connected to the `NetBeans IDE 8.2`, so I can't launch my PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to this documentation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-installation-layout.html if you installed your MySQL using the installer, you could find data directory under %PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\

if you find your data directory there, you can send that location to mysqld using --datadir to let mysql server where to find data files.